# Braodcast receiver not receiving Intent after SMS sent using 4G network

Tags: android, 4g

I am not receiving intent from BroadcastReceiver using 4G network. I am using following code to receive sms sent result in code. I am getting currect result in 2G cell network but not for 4G.
if any body have some idea please reply.
Thanks.

```
registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SENT"));
sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    int result = getResultCode();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                System.out.println("Received response");
                break;  
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                addFailedResultsInList("RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                addFailedResultsInList("RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                addFailedResultsInList("RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU");
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                addFailedResultsInList("RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF");
                break;

        }
    }
};

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: show complete code including manifest!

Comment: where you initialized the result?

Comment: it should be result = getResultCode (); before swtich

Comment: i am not receiving SMS but i am tring to receive sent sms's result after sending sms by this broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Beside creating BroadcastReceiver you also need to register it for events which you want to get. You might wanna follow this tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

When you want to be notified about sms receiving you need to register for event

```
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
```

and request permission for that
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_SMS

Comment: i am not receiving SMS but i am tring to receive sent sms's result after sending sms by this broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        result = getResultCode (); //<-------------------

        switch (result)
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                System.out.println("Received response");
                break;  
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                addFailedResultsInList("RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE");
                break;
```

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zK1JvoJkoQMJ:developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessagingDemo.html+BroadcastReceiver+result+intent+%22getResultCode%22&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in